# Tag video, HTML5, largura 100% e altura controlada

Tags: html5, height

Eu fiz o video full screen na home só que agora eu preciso utilizar o vídeo com a mesma largura de 100% só que com a altura mínima de 400px, mas o video só fica com 400px de altura quando eu retiro os 100% de largura:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" />
<head>
<style>
*{ margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
HTML ,BODY{ height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased; -o-font-smoothing: antialiased; -ms-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
BODY{ text-align:left; }
#site{ width:100%; min-height:100%; position:relative; }
#site #videhome{ position:fixed; right:0; bottom:0; min-width:100%; min-height:100%; width:auto; height:auto; z-index:-100; background-size:contain; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="site"> 
<video autoplay loop id="videhome">
    <source src="video/Falling.Skies.S04E07.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como faço para que o vídeo mantenha os 100% de largura colocando a altura que eu desejar? E se tiver algum jeito de fazer isso, quando o monitor da pessoa for menor como por exemplo 1024x768 o video vai manter a altura ou vai se adaptar?

Comment: Oiii, você quer manter 100% de largura e colocar 400px de altura ? só isso ?

Comment: sim, vou explicar é por que na home eu precisava fazer um video full scream e foi muito fácil, só que nas internas eu preciso fazer como se fosse um banner 100% de largura só que com altura de 400px.
Mas é como eu o video só fica em 400px de altura quando eu tiro a largura de 100% tendeu?

Comment: Cara, eu intendi, é só você mudar o css do id "#videhome", você adiciona o "max-width: 400px;"

Comment: Acho que vc quis dizer max-height né? Eu coloquei aqui max-height o vídeo fica em 400 de altura mas automaticamente a largura dele vai para 713px e mesmo que eu coloque max-with:100% !important; não funciona, tem como fazer isso com javascript?

Answer (score 2):

O tamanho de 100% só funciona se todos os seus pais também estiverem em 100% no css vai precisar disso tb para o html e body:

```
html{width: 100%}
body{width: 100%}
#site{width: 100%}
#videhome{height: 400pt, width: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="video-bg">
  <video autoplay muted>
    <!-- Default video source: -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/myvid.mp4"
            media="(orientation:landscape)">

  </video>
</div>


#video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#video-bg > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* 1. No object-fit support: */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */
@supports (object-fit: cover) {
  #video-bg > video {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

creio que isso ira resolver seus problemas para mais informações acesse esse link [aqui](http://fvsch.com/code/video-background/)